# PostgreSQL query for multiple update

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table in which I have 4 columns: `emp_no`,`desig_name`,`from_date` and `to_date`:

```
emp_no  desig_name       from_date                  to_date
1001    engineer         2004-08-01 00:00:00
1001    sr.engineer      2010-08-01 00:00:00
1001    chief.engineer   2013-08-01 00:00:00
```

So my question is to update first row `to_date` column just one day before `from_date` of second row as well as for the second one aslo?

After update it should look like:

```
emp_no  desig_name       from_date                  to_date
1001    engineer         2004-08-01 00:00:00        2010-07-31 00:00:00
1001    sr.engineer      2010-08-01 00:00:00        2013-07-31 00:00:00
1001    chief.engineer   2013-08-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Is there any unique field on this table?

Comment: yes there is also a colmn name 'promotion_id' that is unique field

Comment: Does promotion_id specify the order of the rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the "next" date using the `lead()` function.

This calculated value can then be used to update the table:

```
with calc as (
  select promotion_id, 
         emp_no, 
         from_date, 
         lead(from_date) over (partition by emp_no order by from_date) as next_date
  from emp
)
update emp 
   set to_date = c.next_date - interval '1' day
from calc c
  where c.promotion_id = emp.promotion_id;
```

As you can see getting that value is quite easy, and storing derived information is very often not a good idea. You might want to consider a view that calculates this information on the fly so you don't need to update your table each time you insert a new row.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/31665/1

Comment: i m not getting it properly ,as per ur answer u first created the function as "calc" then u run the update query ?

Comment: and i m using PostgreSQL9.1

Comment: @Anand: that is one single statement. There is no "function" in my statement. Did you have a look at the SQLFiddle? It will work with Postgres 9.1. And please refrain from using "leet speak". It is a sign of courtesy and respect to write proper sentences - especially if you are asking for free help

Comment: i do apology for that .

Comment: when i m runing that script i m getting this error                                    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "update"
LINE 8: update test_table 
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "update"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 184

Comment: @Anand: then there is something you are not telling us, because it does work with 9.1, see the SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2c194/1

Comment: data type of from_date and to_date is 'timestamp without time zone'    this is my tablescript.                                              
 CREATE TABLE test_table
(
  promotion_id bigint NOT NULL,
  emp_no bigint,
  desig_name character varying(255),
  to_date timestamp without time zone,
  from_date timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT test_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (promotion_id)
)